# How can I append/replace an implementation to a class method in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code first:

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class SomeInterfaceishClass():
    @abstractmethod
    @staticmethod
    def foo(bar):
        pass

class SomeClass(SomeInterfaceishClass):
    @staticmethod
    def foo(bar):
        print("implementation here")

class EventHandler():
    @staticmethod
    @Multitasking.threaded
    def foo(bar):
        pass
```

I'm writing a frameworkish thingy where the end-user is forced to implement a few methods (only one here for simplicity). Therefore I have defined the SomeInterfaceishClass class with a abstract method. My problem is that I will not run the method from this class, instead, I'd like to run it from the EventHandler class. As you can see it has a decorator to make it run async and I think this is where the problem arises.

I know that I can call `EventHandler.foo = getattr(self, 'foo')` in the  constructor of `SomeInterfaceishClass`, but when I do this the complete function will be overridden (loses it's decorator).

I'd like to keep the end-users code as clean as possible and therefore don't really want to add the decorator in `SomeClass`.

Is there any way to accomplish this? For example is there a way to add an implementation to a class method, rather than add a method to a class?

Just to be clear: I want to add it to the EventHandler **class**, not an instance of it.

Thank you all! :)

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to do, or whether it is a good idea... but if the problem is that the decorator is lost when you set the class attribute, then you can just apply the decorator manually: `EventHandler.foo = staticmethod(Multitasking.threaded(self.foo))`.

Comment: Oh wauw, I didn't know the staticmethod function. I can imagine it's not very clear, but it's a big project by now and was trying to keep the example as clean as possible.

Thanks anyway, it seems to have solved my problem :)

Comment: Glad to help. In general, `@something` is syntactic sugar for function application. You can do the same thing with `abstractmethod`, `classmethod`, etc. as I have done here with `staticmethod`.

Comment: Very very cool, thanks for the additional info :)